# With clause execution

Tags: oracle, sybase, teradata, common-table-expression, netezza

I've always thought that `With` clause was working as a one-time execute statement, which behaves as a normal table - you can do all SQL operations on it as you would on a regular table.

But it turned out that in several databases(Oracle, Netezza, Sybase, Teradata) the `with` clause is executed each time it is used.

```
 With Test as(

    select random() --pseudo code

)
select '1st select', * from Test
union
select '2nd select', * form Test
```

Instead of 2 identical numbers, the query above returns 2 different numbers, so it is executed for each of the selects.

If I have a very complex query within a `With` clause and I use it 5 times in the rest of the query, it would execute 5 times which seems very ineffective to me.

So can someone give me a good logical reason is it working this way?

Comment: Postgres returns the same number for both outer selects. So the CTE is only run once there

Comment: In Oracle `WITH test (rnd) AS ( SELECT /*+MATERIALIZE*/ DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE FROM DUAL ) SELECT 'a', t.* FROM test t UNION ALL SELECT 'b', t.* FROM test t;` gives the same number for both.

Comment: FWIW, BigQuery behaves the same, outputting two different values for a random calculation that appears only once in the with clause (and unioned later). I was just wondering how to circumvent this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle:

CTE aka Subquery factoring clause(in Oracle's terminology) can either be INLINEd or MATERIALIZEd, which ever is feasible. CBO should decide what will be more effective. Your example with random() function is a corner case.

Also it does not matter whether WITH clause is executed once or many times.
Each potential re-execution *must* give the *same* result. So decision whether subquery is INLINEd or MATERIALIZEd influences only the performance, but never actual query result.

Try to use hints MATERIALIZE or INLINE to see how exec. plan changes. Your test does not express anything about behavior of real SQL query evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

In the [oracle world](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABFAFID), as explained [here](http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/with.html), The WITH query_name clause lets you assign a name to a subquery block. You can then reference the subquery block multiple places in the query by specifying the query name. Oracle optimizes the query by treating the query name as either an inline view or as a temporary table.

You can specify this clause in any top-level SELECT statement and in most types of subqueries. The query name is visible to the main query and to all subsequent subqueries except the subquery that defines the query name itself.

A WITH clause is most valuable when the result of the WITH query is required more than one time in the body of the main query such as where one averaged value needs to be compared against two or three times. The point is to minimize the number of accesses to a table joined multiple times into a single query.

**Restrictions on Subquery Factoring:**

You cannot nest this clause. That is, you cannot specify the subquery_factoring_clause within the subquery of another subquery_factoring_clause. However, a query_name defined in one subquery_factoring_clause can be used in the subquery of any subsequent subquery_factoring_clause.

In a query with set operators, the set operator subquery cannot contain the subquery_factoring_clause, but the FROM subquery can contain the subquery_factoring_clause.

In your case, you have used a random function which will be treated differently by the optimizer, which will treat it as an inline view rather than a materialized one. As @ibre5041 suggested use a `EXPLAIN PLAN` for different cases.

Consider the case of a recursive CTE, it is used internally everytime.

```
WITH generator ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT value + 1
  FROM   generator
  WHERE  value < 10
)
SELECT value
FROM   generator;

Plan hash value: 1492144221

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |      |     2 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW                                     |      |     2 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION ALL (RECURSIVE WITH) BREADTH FIRST|      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    FAST DUAL                              |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    RECURSIVE WITH PUMP                    |      |       |       |            |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - filter("VALUE"<10)
```

Comment: how do you generate the Explain Plan info like the above, I have been searching for it to do so with the 'WITH' clause present but failed to find the exact step. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At least in `Teradata` it's working as expected, the random value is calculated only once:

```
With Test as(
   select random(1,1000000) as x --pseudo code
)
select '1st select', x from Test
union
select '2nd select', x from Test
;

 *** Query completed. 2 rows found. 2 columns returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

'1st select'            x
------------  -----------
1st select         422654
2nd select         422654
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "as expected" - expectations are different for different people. I have only ever worked with Oracle. I read the documentation for subquery factoring, and what I "expect" in this case is to get different values, because that is the stated, documented behavior of the CTE in this case (in Oracle).

Comment: @mathguy: That's why there are Standards and based on Standard SQL a *Common Table Expression* must return the same data when accessed multiple times.

Comment: If a vendor chooses to disregard the standards (as they are free to), and they document it, then I still "expect" a feature to behave as documented by the vendor, not as the standard says. In Oracle, I expect `null || 'x'` to return `'x'`, when I know full well the standard requires `null`. I agree with the standard and I find Oracle's choices odd (or sometimes outright stupid), but I still expect the behavior to be what Oracle says, when I use their product.

Comment: @mathguy: But Oracle documents *"T121, WITH (excluding RECURSIVE) in query expression
 Oracle fully supports this feature."* in https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_standard_sql004.htm#SQLRF55521

Comment: OK, fair enough; this is a different, and much stronger, argument. (I see how they are related though, since the Oracle documentation says "fully supports.") All I can say to that is "Oracle documentation." 'nuff said! You are right.